# verbose parameter not working in PMML pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, lightgbm, pmml

I am trying to put my gbdt+lr pipeline into PMML pipeline. Followed instruction [here](https://openscoring.io/blog/2019/06/19/sklearn_gbdt_lr_ensemble/), this is my test code:

```
gbm = lgb.LGBMClassifier(n_estimators=100)
clf = GBDTLRClassifier(gbm, LogisticRegression(penalty='l2'))
pipeline = PMMLPipeline([('classifier', clf)])
pipeline.fit(x, y, classifier__gbm_early_stopping_rounds=5, classifier__gbm_eval_set=[(xv, yv)], classifier__gbm_eval_metric='logloss', classifier__gbm_verbose = 2)
```

During fitting period, the `verbose` parameter not working. Same setting works well in simple lightgbm classifier. Do anyone have idea about why `verbose` not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do anyone have idea about why verbose not working?

Does Scikit-Learn issue any warnings or errors? Such as that "'classifier' does not have 'gbm' attribute"?

You can take a look at `GBDTLRClassifier` source code [here](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml/blob/master/sklearn2pmml/ensemble/__init__.py).

The attribute that holds GBDT classifier is called `GBDTLRClassifier.gbdt` (instead of `GBDTLRClassifier.gbm`). Therefore, if you prefix your fit parameters with `classifier__gbdt` (instead of `classifier__gbm`), then everything should work fine:

```
pipeline = PMMLPipeline([('classifier', clf)])
pipeline.fit(x, y, classifier__gbdt__verbose = 2)
```

Comment: Actually there is not any warning or error. The fitting process worked well. And one more thing that confused me is that I thought the prefix should be `gbdt` instead of self-defined variable name, but when I use `gbdt`, my pipeline issue error on no eval_set and eval metric for `early_stopping_rounds`. After changed to `gbm`, it works. That's really wired.

Comment: See the definition of the `_step_params(name, params)` function inside the GBDTLRClassifier class. The param prefix for `gbdt` and `lr` sub-estimators is constructed using two underscore characters (not one). Therefore, you should try `classifier__gbdt__early_stopping_rounds`.

Comment: you are right, I missed that part of source code. thx and accepted